# Fire click event on a div excluding one child div and it's descendents

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Inside that I have other child divs. Those have child divs too.

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child_1">//children elements</div>
<div class="child_1">//children elements</div>
<div class="child_1">//children elements</div>
<div class="child_1">//children elements</div>
</div>
```

I want to add a click event that fires when I click any element inside **parent** div, including **parent** div, excluding **child_1** div and its descendants.

Currently I tried with

```
jQuery(".parent").not(".child_1").click(function(event) {

});
```

But the click event works when I click on **child_1** div and it's descendants.

What is the problem here? please help.

**UPDATE**

here i have another click event for  **child_1**

```
jQuery(".child_1").click(function(event) {

});
```

Comment: can u send ur example in JSfiddle...

Answer (score 5):

You should do it like this.

```
$('.parent').on('click', function () {
  // do your stuff here
}).find('.child_1').on('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BbX7D/1/

Answer (score 1):

You still have to catch the click event on the elements that you want to exclude, otherwise the click will just bubble up to the `.parent` element.

Use the `closest` method to check if the clicked element is, or is a child of, an element with the class `.child_1`. Use `stopPropagation` to keep the event from bubbling:

```
$('.parent,.parent *').click(function(e){
  if ($(this).closest('.child_1').length > 0) {
    alert('in child_1');
  } else {
    alert('not in child_1');
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/tETCQ/

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
jQuery(".parent, .parent *").not(".child_1").click(function(event) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyh4A/3/)):

*(edit + updated fiddle)*
I spotted a flaw. This version checks if the clicked element is or is inside an element which has the class 'exclude':

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child_1 exclude">//children elements</div>
<div class="child_1">//children elements</div>
<div class="child_1">//children elements</div>
<div class="child_1">//children elements</div>
</div>

jQuery(".parent").click(function(event) 
    {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.exclude').length>0) return false; 
    alert('hi');
    });
```

Comment: I used the exclude class since all your children are called child_1. You could also use `$(event.target).closest('.parent').children().get(0)==event.target`. Using a click event on only `.parent` will work fine if you're not explicitly cancelling any propagations in any click functions that the other children might have.

Answer (score 0):

a bit of an old question, but figured i'd throw out my resolution in case it helps anyone else.

this is pretty much what i did. this example uses your markup:

```
$('.parent').on('click', function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if (!$target.parents('.child_1').length && !$target.hasClass('child_1')) {
        // do what you need on the parent's click event
        // add 'e.preventDefault()' here if you need
    }
    // no need to prevent default or stop propagation here
    // this will allow click events on child elements to work
});
```