# Exclude tag from submit area

Tags: jquery, html, css, tags, submit

I have a `<p>` tag that is used as a submit button/area via a specific id in jquery.

```
<p id="xyz"></p>
```

I need to place a input field inside this `<p>` tag to include a specific value that is submitted via jquery ajax post method.

```
<p id="xyz"><input type="number"></p>
```

When I click inside the input area, the jquery ajax submit process is started. How can I prevent that? I just want to start the submit process after I filled in a number in the input and click beside it in the rest of the `<p>` tag area.

(The input can not be placed beside the `<p>` tag.)

thank you in advance.

best greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think that something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393902/fire-click-event-on-a-div-excluding-one-child-div-and-its-descendents) might work. You basically need to stop the click event of the parent element (p) from continuing execution.